# Secure file upload utilizing an algorithm in the name of the file supposed to be uploaded

Tags: php, android, algorithm

About secure file upload utilizing PHP,
I wonder,
If utilizing a dynamic secret key in the name of the file which is supposed to be uploaded and then verifying the name in PHP file before upload, could be enough or no?
I mean, searching the net I found several security issues like renaming the file or verifying file extension or verifying "PHP" not be in the name of the file, ...
but if a secret key algorithm would be accomplished in the name of the file, if there is still the possibility of hacking the server or not (assuming the algorithm is not hacked)?

> Example: File Name: ABCDEFGH.jpg

ABCD will change from file to file
EFGH is calculated with a secret algorithm which utilizes ABCD as input and the result is put in the name (EFGH)

Now when the file is going to be uploaded to the server, ABCD as input and the result EFGH would be verified in PHP file
So if EFGH is generated out of ABCD by the algorithm, the file is allowed to be uploaded if no, it is rejected

Thanks in advance

Comment: how android code can be seen?

Comment: So a company makes an APK and another company can simply receive the source code of the apk and then utilize it for its new or the same apk ? Is n't there a procedure to protect the source code ?

Comment: many thanks for your comments , I got a software and viewed all parts of my application, Now I think I should look for code protection procedures!